# what to use instead of two-way ANOVA for the trimodal data

Tags: anova, normality-assumption

I have a continuous dependent variable that varies from -0.5 to +0.5. It is clearly not normally distributed with three peaks (at -0.5, 0 and +0.5):

[[image]]
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFDVp.png)

I have two categorical variables (TreatmentX3, GenderX2), which I would like to use in two-way ANOVA. But since the dependent variable is so clearly non-normal, what can I use instead?

Comment: Can you explain how is the plot you provided related to your question. I see multiple peaks, and some numbers like -30 and 30. Where do I see peaks at -0.5, 0, 0.5?

Comment: yes, sorry, a misleading plot: that is the actual data, but the values are multiplied by 100 (so the peaks are at -50, 0, 50) and some values in between (-30 etc)

Comment: These data by themselves tell us little about the applicability of ANOVA.  The distributions of the *residuals* matter far more.  Why don't you run an ANOVA and show us those residuals?  How many observations are in each group?  (Relatively large counts will overcome many potential distributional problems.)

Answer (score 3):

Use the generalization of the Kruskal-Wallis test: the semiparametric proportional odds ordinal logistic regression model.   This model allows for adjustment for covariates, interactions, etc., while only using the rank ordering within Y.  Much more information may be found in the Nonparametrics chapter of [BBR](https://hbiostat.org/bbr) and in a case study on ordinal regression for continuous Y in a chapter in [RMS](https://hbiostat.org/rms).

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `t2way` function from the WRS or WRS2 package in R with post-hoc test accessible through `mcp2atm`. This function computes a two-way ANOVA by default on 20% trimmed means. The question remains whether this amount of trimming is appropriate. Generally you should select a measure of location that represents your data best, i.e. with the lowest standard error for the DV which might be the 20% trimmed mean or not.
You can test the SE of you DV with the function `trimse` (available in WRS or WRS2) like this:

```
library(WRS2)
trimse(DV) # for 20% trimmed means
trimse(DV, tr = 0.1) # for 10% tr. mean
trimse(DV, tr = 0) # for standard arithmetic mean
```

Sometimes the median can represent you data the best in this case estimate the standard error for the median of your DV like this:

```
# load the WRS package
source("https://dornsife.usc.edu/assets/sites/239/docs/Rallfun-v38.txt")
bootse(DV) #SE for the median of you DV
```

If you obtain the lowest standard error for your DV with this function, ask me and I will show how to compute a robust ANOVA on medians.

Alternatively you can forget about this all and use a non-parametric two-way test on ranks by Brunner et al. called `bdm2way` accessible through WRS or with `BDM.2way` from the asbio package. The disadvantage is that a non-parametric test might not always be as powerful as the former methods.

```
library(asbio)
BDM.2way(DV, TreatmentX3, TreatmentX2)
```

Comment: Why would one choose trimmed means for these data?  They have such low skewness and kurtosis that ordinary ANOVA could do a great job.